# Show data using json in scrolling tabview and recycler view.tabview=category name,Listview=products

Tags: android, json, listview, parsing, tabview

I have a list of hotel names and I want to display the categories of products in scrolling tab view using JSON (as tab name) and the products of respective category in recyclerview or listview. Please give any example regarding this.

API's are :
http://ibookstay.com/oops/restapi/all-restaurant

http://ibookstay.com/oops/restapi/category-with-product

Comment: can you elaborate your question and it is better if you post a sketch to support your description